# Нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Мужчина объяснил, где найти транспорт и как добраться до границы.
2. Четырехзвездочный отель, после ночлега на полу, показался мне эдемским садом.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

*Мужчина объяснил, где найти транспорт и как добраться до границы.* Объяснил (что?) После главного предложения, завершённого запятой,  идут два однородных придаточных, соединённых союзом И. Запятая перед И в этом случае не ставится.

Второе предложение построено не совсем корректно. Если же надо говорить только о знаках, то такой вариант постановки запятых возможен. Запятые выделяют часть предложения со смысловым акцентом.

Comment: Екатерина, а что неправильно там?

Comment: *Второе предложение построено не совсем корректно* - )))) Екатерина, тут действительно надо написать, что это не отель  ночевал на полу, ибо не всем понятно.

Comment: Да, я как раз это и имела в виду. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Запятые нужны. Первая отделяет придаточное от главного. Во втором запятая отделяет обособленное обстоятельство "после ночлега на полу".

> Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.
>   Ср.: **Петя, после полученного им решительного отказа, ушёл в свою комнату и там, запершись от всех, горько плакал (Л. Т.).**

[См.: Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112#pp112)

Answer (score 0):

Первое предложение написано правильно, запятая одна, больше не нужно, т. к. там две равноправные части предложения - "где найти" и "как добраться", соединенные союзом "и".

Во втором предложении не нужно вообще запятых.

Comment: Без запятых получается, что на полу ночевал отель. С запятыми - и то двусмысленность...